# custom user model Django - AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model that has not been installed

Tags: python, django

I created my custom user model which inherits from `AbstractBaseUser`. My model is located in `api/models/userModel.py` file. Api is the name of my application which I registered in `INSTALLED_APPS` in settings.py. I register my custom user model in settings.py with
`AUTH_USER_MODEL='api.UserAccount'`.
My problem is whenever I try to `py manage.py makemigrations` I get error: `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'api.UserAccount' that has not been installed`
I tried to delete all migrations files and reset my DB but it doesn't work. Do you have any idea what is wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to import your models in `api/models/__init__.py` file if you have a custom file-structure, so Django can discover them:

```
from .userModel import UserAccount
```

Comment: I didn't mention that but I created that already, it doesn't work either

Comment: Ok so i noticed when I put my custom user model inside models.py which is next to userModel.py in the structure of files it works fine, but when it is in it's own file it doesn't work, do you have any idea why I can't have two files of models in one directory ? I have exported them in __init__.py

Answer (score 0):

Since you say that having UserAccount inside models.py is working, maybe you'd consider to try importing it in models.py insted of __init__.py. This will include this model in default file and make it be separate.